# Devel::Cover - only subroutine coverage

Tags: perl, devel-cover

I want only subroutine coverage in my perl file.
So in main file I inserted the following statement:

#### mainfile.pl

```
use Devel::Cover::Subroutine;
```

If I run mainfile.pl it shows the error:

```
Devel::Cover: Writing coverage database to /home/devel1/Devel-Cover-0.78/examples1/cover_db/runs/1319109459.10082.56199
Can't find digest for mainfile.pl at /opt/perl_32/lib/site_perl/5.8.8/IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi/Devel/Cover/DB/Structure.pm line 282.
Devel::Cover: Can't find digest for mainfile.pl
--------------------------------------------------------------- ------ ------
File                                                               sub  total
--------------------------------------------------------------- ------ ------
Total                                                              n/a    n/a
--------------------------------------------------------------- ------ ------
```

How can I resolve this error?
But when I use only `use Devel::Cover;` it works properly.

Comment: cursader: don't use HTML markup in your posts, but do use proper capitalization. There is a `?` button in the editor to learn how to insert code.

Answer (score 6):

`Devel::Cover::Subroutine` is an internal module used by Devel::Cover to represent subroutine coverage data. You should not use this directly. Instead, you should use `Devel::Cover` with the `-subs_only` option.